# Display Seconds Count in HH:MM:SS format in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table with a column, TotalTime that is an Integer value in seconds.

In Visual Studio / SSRS 2008 I want to display it in HH:MM:SS format.

Thanks!

Comment: My only issue with the answer provided by Chris is that it doesn't seem to take into account rounding (i.e., 5.5 seconds becomes 5 seconds rather than being rounded to 6). While I can't take credit for the solution, I was able to implement the one using custom code recommended [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b80ed2e5-0206-42e1-a9b4-9dace4f95406/convert-seconds-to-days-hours-minutes-seconds-in-reporting-services?forum=sqlreportingservices).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just use an expression that adds that number of seconds to a zero time value

```
=Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!TotalTime.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

If it is larger than 24 hours, then you can use the following formula that adds the days portion:

```
=IIF(Fields!TotalTime.Value < 86400, 
    Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!TotalTime.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"), 
    Floor(Fields!TotalTime.Value / 86400) & " days, " & Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!TotalTime.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: Hi Chris, in case you are interested, I just asked a new question that is like a continuation of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534686/how-to-display-beyond-24-hrs-in-ssrs-2008-in-hhmmss-format  Thanks!!!

Comment: This answer actually does not work if it goes on for multiple days.

Comment: @Tanner_Gram It does now

Answer (score 10):

For HH:mm:ss format you can use this:

```
=Floor(Fields!TotalTime.Value / 3600) &":"& Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!TotalTime.Value, "00:00"), "mm:ss")
```

In this case, for example 90000sec will be displayed as: **25:00:00**

For DD:HH:mm:ss format use this:

```
Floor(Fields!TotalTime.Value / 86400) &":"& Format(DateAdd("s", Fields!TotalTime.Value, "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

90000sec will be shown as: **1:01:00:00**