# How do I format a timespan in SSRS to show more than 24 total hours in HH:MM:SS?

Tags: reporting-services, format, timespan

I want to add a total row in SSRS table to calculate total call time. 
Since total call time is more than 24, i used Timespan expression which produces a result

= system.TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!Call_Time.Value))

However, i am seeing the total hours formatted 11.15:02:45 while i want to see it in HH:mm:ss format.

How can I format the above Timespan expression to show the >24 hours total time in hh:mm:ss?

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13482765/2647648)? just replace `Fields!TotalTime.Value` by `Sum(Fields!Call_Time.Value)`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i don't have a totalTime field. Total time is calculated from this expression = system.TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!Call_Time.Value))

Comment: I mean you have to replace the `Fields!TotalTime.Value` field in the expression provided in that answer by `Sum(Fields!Call_Time.Value)` expression you use to calculate the total.

Comment: Got it. When i do that, i'm getting one big number (26925000) instead of hh:mm:ss format.

Comment: Note `Call_Time` should represent seconds in order to that expression work. Otherwise you might want to perform the calculation to convert `Call_Time` value to seconds.