# Integer into HH.MM in ssrs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2012

How to convert integer into HH.MM in ssrs ? Ex: If 3600 is integer then output should be 01.00

Comment: By what logic do you *want* to convert an integer into hours and minutes?  How does the value *represent* hours and minutes?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What does the number represent?

Comment: Please provide your table data

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: If Integer(seconds) is 3600 then i want output as 01.00 ,28800 sec then output is 08.00

Comment: @SiddarthaGr: So you want to perform division operations and modulo operations.  What have you tried?

Comment: I tried Floor(Sum(Fields!WORKED_HOURS.Value) / 3600) &":"& Format(DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!WORKED_HOURS.Value), "00:00"), "mm:ss") which is giving output as 8:30:00   but i want 08.30

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Seconds Count in HH:MM:SS format in SSRS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481890/display-seconds-count-in-hhmmss-format-in-ssrs-2008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would question why you are wanting to present your data in this way and suggest that you consider a different approach, such as adding the seconds to a start time, depending on your data and reporting requirements.

In short, try your best to avoid text formatting within SQL.  It is not built to do this.

---

That aside, to answer your question; this is fairly standard integer division and modulo based maths.  You want to firstly convert your seconds into minutes by dividing by 60 and then into hours by dividing by 60 again.  A modulo can be used instead to get the minutes remaining from the hour calculation.  The rest is text formatting:

```
declare @t table (s int);
insert into @t values(3600),(28800)

select s
        ,right('00' + cast(s/60/60 as varchar(2)),2) + '.' + right('00' + cast(s/60%60 as varchar(2)),2) as Formatted
from @t
```

Output:

```
+---+-------+-----------+
|   |   s   | Formatted |
+---+-------+-----------+
| 1 |  3600 | 01:00     |
| 2 | 28800 | 08:00     |
+---+-------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @s int;
set @s = 3760

select right('00' + cast (@s/3600 as nvarchar(max)) , 2) +':' +right('00' +cast((@s % 3600)/60 as nvarchar(max)) ,2)
```

simply use math operators for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your time,But i want this in SSRS

Comment: take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481890/display-seconds-count-in-hhmmss-format-in-ssrs-2008